# Why did Bramha stop Hanuman from killing/defeating Ravana?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, brahma, ravana

According to Ramayana there was a scene when Ravana challenged Hanuman for a single punch fight. Ravana gave a punch to Hanuman but when Hanuman was about to punch back he was stopped by Brahma.

Why was it so? If Hanuman would have defeated Ravana at that time, so many good lives of those who died in Ramayana war could have been saved.

Comment: There is no scene like that. There is a punching match between them but it ends at that. There is no intervention by Brahmaji

Comment: There is you will find it

Comment: As far as I know, @Adiyarkku is correct and there is no such scene, at least not in any of the major retellings. However, if we're wrong, you have to actually _tell us where it is_. You should provide the verse/verse number and perhaps link a pdf for us.

Comment: Sure will find it and share

Comment: In the video below you can find .... Here the reason that Brahma ji gave isn't that worthy ................................ https://youtube.com/shorts/tJcHt0OWMs0?feature=share

Comment: There is no such incident in which Brahma stops the fight.

Comment: That video is wrong.